# Get the real size of received packet

Tags: c, winsock2

**Usually when sending arbitrarily sized packets, a maximum is established and used as the size of your receive buffer.**

```
#include <winsock2.h>

// Socket Description
// Hint.ai_family = AF_INET;
// Hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
// Hint.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;

void Send(int Size)
{
    char *Data = (char *)malloc(Size);
    sendto(Socket, Data, Size, NULL, Result->ai_addr, Result->ai_addrlen)
}

void Receive()
{
    const unsigned int MaxDataSize = 1436;
    char *Data = (char *)malloc(MaxDataSize);
    recvfrom(Socket, Data, MaxDataSize, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&RecvAddr, &RecvAddrSize);
}
```

In this pseudo example, no matter the size of data passed to `Send()`, our `Receive()` function always gets it at the maximum size defined.

**How can one ascertain the original sent packets size?**

Comment: You need to provide more context, like what kind of socket is it? What is the size of the data you send? And you *do* check the result of `sendto` and `recvfrom`? Also, this is pretty much unrelated to C++ (or you would use `new` instead of `malloc`) so please update the tags. Tag spamming is frowned upon.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [*man* page for *recvfrom()*](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom)?

Comment: `recvfrom` returns the size of the packet...

Comment: Thanks guys I completely overlooked the return value. I'm sure someone else will stumble here in the future as I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN recvfrom() Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120(v=vs.85).aspx)

> If no error occurs, recvfrom returns the number of bytes received. If
>   the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero.
>   Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error
>   code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError.

Subsequently, through the use of the `MSG_PEEK` flag:

> Peeks at the incoming data. The data is copied into the buffer but is
>   not removed from the input queue. The function subsequently returns
>   the amount of data that can be read in a single call to the recvfrom
>   (or recv) function, which may not be the same as the total amount of
>   data queued on the socket. The amount of data that can actually be
>   read in a single call to the recvfrom (or recv) function is limited to
>   the data size written in the send or sendto function call.

This gives you the flexibility to read an incoming packet in multiple bursts. Allowing you to append a size value to the beginning of a packet before sending it off. This however does not seem as trivial as it sounds.

I question any performance gains from going this route instead of just allocating enough memory outright to hold the biggest packet you'll ever send.

Comment: Your question was "How can one ascertain the original sent packets size?". This has got nothing to do with the size of the receive buffer; you've missed the point. You can't tell the receiver just to fill up the receive buffer, or to read the whole packet, whatever that means. You *must* read the incoming packet in multiple bursts, period. The size of the receive buffer is not an issue.

Comment: @EML: what you say is true for TCP, but not for UDP. UDP preserves message boundaries, where a single call to `sendto()` (or a connected `send()`) sends a complete message, and a single call to `recvfrom()` (or a connected `recv()`)  reads a complete message and returns its full size. If the buffer is not large enough to receive the complete message in a single read, a `WSAEMSGSIZE` error is reported and the message is lost, unless `MSG_PEEK` is used. There is no need to embed the actual message length inside a UDP message's payload, except maybe for integrity checking.

Comment: @Remy - I didn't notice the UDP/DGRAM comment - thanks - answer withdrawn.